# ios ble "Characteristic User Description"

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

Trying to retrieve readable information from an characteristics by using the function:

```
peripheral.discoverDescriptors(for: characteristic)
```

Later the delegate method:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverDescriptorsFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)
```

is called but how can I get the string description? When I read the value from the descriptors it's always `nil`.

```
let descriptors = characteristic.descriptors! as [CBDescriptor]
for descriptor in descriptors {
    print("\(#function): descriptor = \(descriptor) UUID = \(descriptor.uuid) value = \(descriptor.value)")
}
```

However, if I'm browsing and connecting with an BLE scanner it can read the characteristic human readable descriptors.

Comment: what is being printed out in your debug console?

Comment: any update on this? I'm also facing same issue on reading the Format, Unit, Exponent, Name Space and Description of the descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

Reading descriptors is a two-step process, much like discovering and then reading characteristics.

Try:

```
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverDescriptorsFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    guard let descriptors = characteristic.descriptors else { return }

    for descr in descriptors {
        peripheral.readValue(for: descr)
    }
}
```

And then fill in the blanks of:

```
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor descriptor: CBDescriptor, error: Error?) {
    switch descriptor.uuid.uuidString {
    case CBUUIDCharacteristicExtendedPropertiesString:
        guard let properties = descriptor.value as? NSNumber else {
            break
        }
        print("  Extended properties: \(properties)")
    case CBUUIDCharacteristicUserDescriptionString:
        guard let description = descriptor.value as? NSString else {
            break
        }
        print("  User description: \(description)")
    case CBUUIDClientCharacteristicConfigurationString:
        guard let clientConfig = descriptor.value as? NSNumber else {
            break
        }
        print("  Client configuration: \(clientConfig)")
    case CBUUIDServerCharacteristicConfigurationString:
        guard let serverConfig = descriptor.value as? NSNumber else {
            break
        }
        print("  Server configuration: \(serverConfig)")
    case CBUUIDCharacteristicFormatString:
        guard let format = descriptor.value as? NSData else {
            break
        }
        print("  Format: \(format)")
    case CBUUIDCharacteristicAggregateFormatString:
        print("  Aggregate Format: (is not documented)")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

The string constants and the associated data types came from the overview table [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbdescriptor).

In my (limited) experience, descriptors don't reveal anything particularly interesting.